# Unable to Edit Messages - MessageCantBeEdited Error in aiogram

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, aiogram

i was making a gpt 3.5 integrated telegram bot and i wanted to edit texts with bot. I had tried for a long and it worked once. But it's not working now.

```
@dp.message_handler()
async def echo_msg(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply("Hi")
    time.sleep(0.5)
    await message.edit_text("hello")
```

this is my test code where i once did successfully edited a text but it doesn't work now. aiogram.utils.exceptions.MessageCantBeEdited: Message can't be edited. Please help me

I wanted it to edit it normally. Yesterday I was trying to edit by message id and chat id but it gave unexpected value error so i tried removing everything except the text and it worked at that time. But it doesn't now i don't know why.

Comment: can you add the full code and error to the question

Answer (score 1):

You can't edit a user's message; you can only edit the bot's own message.

```
@dp.message_handler()
async def echo_msg(user_message: types.Message):
    bot_message = await user_message.reply("Hi")
    time.sleep(0.5)
    await bot_message.edit_text("hello")
```